# Combobox Validation Rule

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

Hi people do you maybe help me with my question? I have a `Form` with `combobox` and `Panel`. I need when I selected in `Combobox (item1 = yes,item2=no) item 2`, panel make `visible=false` (with all item have), and items that are not visible in panel(`radiobutton, textbox` etc.) the table in database write null for this items. Excuse me! for my grammar error ;) **This is my Form**

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by `Combobox (item1 = yes,item2=no) item 2` and `the table in database write null for this items`?

Comment: I had in mind that combobox are two textes (example: " yes,i do " and "no"), when I select "no" panel make  not visible  with all the options it have, and i need to write in database (text "NULL") for option there are not visible in panel when i select "NO". You understand my idea?

Comment: winforms apllication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On `ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged` write code

```
If ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0 Then 'Also take ComboBox1.SelectedItem='Yes'
            Panel1.Visible = True
        Else
            Panel1.Visible = False
 If RadioButton1.Checked = False Then
           Label1.Text="NULL"
        End If
        End If
```

Pass Label Value to the database.

Comment: but now how so I could write in  database null for "Seria"and "Numarul"(-image)

Comment: Seria value is a textbox value?

Comment: @Cristina Will be better to use `SelectionChangeCommitted` event handler